# Word 2010 Tables

Tags: c#

i have a word template full of bookmarks, however im getting stuck when trying to insert a table... firstly i was issued with a COMException saying the requested member of the collection does not exsist.. ive pressume this means that the bookmark that was set was named differently to what my table is now called.. anyhow, the table does not display at all.. i have set the formatting before the data gets entered to the table...
like so:

```
   // Insert Table


            Word.Table tbl1 = this.Tables[1];
            Tables.Add(Range: tbl1.Range, NumColumns: 2, NumRows: 2);
            tbl1.Range.Font.Size = 10;
            tbl1.Range.Font.Name = "Georgia";
            tbl1.Range.Font.Bold.Equals(true);
            tbl1.Range.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
            tbl1.Range.Cells.Shading.Texture = Word.WdTextureIndex.wdTexture10Percent;
            tbl1.Range.Cells.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdBlue;
            tbl1.Range.Cells.VerticalAlignment = Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;
            tbl1.Rows.SetHeight(RowHeight: 24, HeightRule: Word.WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightAtLeast);
            tbl1.Columns[1].SetWidth(ColumnWidth: 170, RulerStyle: Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
            tbl1.Columns[2].SetWidth(ColumnWidth: 310, RulerStyle: Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustNone);
            tbl1.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;
            tbl1.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleNone;

            // end of table insert
```

then the code that fills the table is after...

```
 if (multipleLimits.Equals(false))
            {
                tbl1.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Indemnity Limit:";
            }
            else
            {
                tbl1.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = IndemlimitsText(iIndemnLimit).ToString();
            }


            switch (typeOfInsID)
            {
                case "4":
                    tbl1.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Public/Products Liability:";
                    break;
            }

            tbl1.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Excess:";

            if (multipleLimits.Equals(false))
            {
                tbl1.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = sCurType + iIndemnLimit;
            }
            else
            {
                tbl1.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = stripIndemLimitCode(iIndemnLimit).ToString();
            }
```

etc, etc... 
my question really is, should the table display even if there is no data to get parsed... say if i wanted to test the parsing data line by line?? or does the code that fills the table need to be present and correct just for the table to display???

i hope i havnt rambled too much and confused my question..

 thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, the table should show, even if all cells are empty.
I guess your range is the problem here, for

```
object endOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
string totRows = 2;
string totColumns = 2;

word.Range wrdRng = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref endOfDoc).Range;
oTable = doc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, totRows, totColumns, ref missing, ref missing);
```

will add the table with 2 columns and 2 rows to the end of the document. You try to add to the range of the table (tbl1.Range) but that is popably the inner Range inside the table itself (containing your cells so to say) You want to add to a paragraph or something else outside the table. The endOfDoc is a bookmark that can be used to add stuff to the end of the document.

Because I don't know what template you are using you could try this first and then figure out the correct bookmark name you need. That can be defined the same way as the endOfDoc in the code above,